How to position the legend at the bottom-left of the graph in a Graphviz flowchart?
I'm working on a flowchart using Graphviz and need to position the legend at the bottom-left of the graph. Below is the code I am currently using, where I have added a subgraph for the legend. By default, the legend is placed at the top, but I would like to move it to the bottom-left.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:

digraph flowchart {
  
  # Graph
  graph [
    overlap = true
    fontsize = 10
  ]
  
  # Define styles for Datasets and Analyses
  node [fontname = 'Calibri Light', fontcolor = white, style = filled]
  
  # Datasets (boxes)
  node [shape = box, fillcolor = firebrick3]  # Set dataset style
  A
  B
  
  # Analyses (circles)
  node [shape = circle, fixedsize = true, width = .9, fillcolor = steelblue3]
  C
  D
  
  # Edges
  {A B}->C
  A->D
  
  # Subgraph for legend
  subgraph cluster_legend {
    graph [
      label = 'Legend'
      labelloc = 't'
      labeljust= 'l'
      fontname = 'Calibri Light'
      color = lightgrey
    ]
    
    # Global node style
    node [fontsize = 9]
    
    # Legend entry for Analysis
    node [shape = circle, fixedsize = true, fillcolor = steelblue3, width = .5, height = .3]
    legend_analysis [label = 'Analysis']
    
    # Legend entry for Data
    node [shape = box, fillcolor = firebrick3, width = .5, height = .5]
    legend_data [label = 'Data']
    
    # Make legend items horizontal
    {rank = same; legend_data; legend_analysis}
  }
}

Could anyone suggest how I can move the legend to the bottom-left of the graph?

try legend[x=left, y=bottom]

Here is one way.

Split the graph into two complete graphs (same input file) (see below)
run through dot, producing xdot output format (https://www.graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/)
run that through gvpack (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) to combine the two graphs, with arguments -array_il1 to stack the two graphs one-over-the-other, left justified
run that through neato -n2 -T... to produce the image. (see https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)

Kind of convoluted, but this way you don't need invisible nodes/edges to try to coerce the Legend into the desired position.
/*******************************************************************
  create a second graph containing the legend
  use gvpack to combine the two,
  then neato -n2 to create image
********************************************************************/
digraph flowchart {
  subgraph cluster_main {  //  sometimes helps w/ gvpack
  # Graph
  graph [
    //  overlap = true  //  dot ignores overlap
    fontsize = 10
  ]
  
  # Define styles for Datasets and Analyses
  node [fontname = "Calibri Light", fontcolor = white, style = filled]
  
  # Datasets (boxes)
  node [shape = box, fillcolor = firebrick3]  # Set dataset style
  A
  B
  
  # Analyses (circles)
  node [shape = circle, fixedsize = true, width = .9, fillcolor = steelblue3]
  C
  D
  
  # Edges
  {A B}->C
  A->D
  }
}
/**  now the legend  **/
digraph L {
 # Subgraph for legend
  subgraph cluster_legend {
    graph [
      label = "Legend"
      labelloc = "t"
      labeljust= "l"
      fontname = "Calibri Light"
      color = lightgrey
    ]
    
    # Global node style
    node [fontsize = 9]
    
    # Legend entry for Analysis
    node [shape = circle, fixedsize = true, fillcolor = steelblue3, width = .5, height = .3]
    legend_analysis [label = "Analysis"]
    
    # Legend entry for Data
    node [shape = box, fillcolor = firebrick3, width = .5, height = .5]
    legend_data [label = "Data"]
    
    # Make legend items horizontal
    {rank = same; legend_data; legend_analysis}
  }
}

And command line (note dot output format is xdot):
dot myFile.gv | gvpack -array_il1 |neato -n2 -T...

Giving:


Thanks. I wonder if there's a more straightforawrd approach that would not requiere combining two different graphs.

Can you insert the legend into an HTML table.  That could be used as the Graph's label and positioned at the lower left.
